# regular expression to extract only Customerid and Data (bytes) and save in list?

Tags: python, regex

I have the below logs

```
01-01-2012 01:13:36 Blah blah : blah CustomerId:1234 downloaded Blah Size:5432 bytes Carrier:Company-A   
01-01-2012 01:13:36 Blah blah : blah CustomerId:1237 downloaded Blah Size:5432 bytes Carrier:Company-B
```

Can somebody tell me a regular expression to extract Customer id and Size and save in list and print how much data downloaded by each customer id? I was able to do this using search and Dictionaries in Python. request you guys to provide using regular expressions.

Comment: You're going to need something a bit more complicated than a simple regular expression if you're intending to summarize results and group them by `CustomerId`.

Comment: The regex to catch id and size would be `/CustomerId:(\d+).*Size:(\d+)/`.

Comment: @eddiem, How about extracting Customer id and Size and save them in different lists and after using Dictionary (Key,Pair). but just wondering if we can use regular expressions to achieve the solution

Comment: Please show what you have already tried that is not working. We need a [mcve]. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service!

Comment: If you're going to pass Perl / PCRE regex to `grep`, you need to use `-P`.

Comment: @ikegami, I know its a perl, sorry i just realized i have tagged Perl also( thinking that they know better Linux regular expressions) removing Perl Tag now.

Comment: @PerlDuck,ikegami,Dezza, Guys i have done research and posted here for different solution, you might have irritated may be because my edit skills, i am very new here. i will get know the edit techniques make it proper next time. excuse me for that. my question  got -4 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, I used your two lines of input data pasted three times in the `data.txt` input test file:

Python:

```
import re

data = {}
regex = re.compile(r'CustomerId:(\d+).*?Size:(\d+)');

with open('data.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        m = regex.search(line)

        if (m.group(1) and m.group(2)):

            cust = m.group(1)
            size = m.group(2)

            try:
                data[cust] += int(size) 
            except KeyError:
                data[cust] = int(size)

print(str(data))
```

Output:

```
{'1234': 16296, '1237': 16296}
```

Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die $!;

my %data;

while (my $line = <$fh>){
    if (my ($cust, $size) = $line =~ /CustomerId:(\d+).*?Size:(\d+)/){
        $data{$cust} += $size;
    }
}

print Dumper \%data;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '1234' => 16296,
      '1237' => 16296
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

res = dict()

data = open("log.txt").readlines()

for line in data:
    m = re.search("CustomerId:([0-9]+).*Size:([0-9]+)", line)
    cid = int(m.group(1))
    siz = int(m.group(2))
    if not res.has_key(cid):
        res[cid] = 0
    res[cid] += siz

for cust in res.keys():
    print "Customer ID %d - %d bytes" % (cust, res[cust])
```

Comment: Eddiem@  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
In [1]: import collections, re

In [2]: d = collections.defaultdict(list)

In [3]: string = "01-01-2012 01:13:36 Blah blah : blah CustomerId:1234 downloaded Blah Size:5432 bytes Carrier:Company-A\n01-01-2012 01:13:36 Blah blah : blah CustomerId:1237 downloaded Bla
    ...: h Size:5432 bytes Carrier:Company-B"

In [4]: for cust_id, sz in re.findall(r".*CustomerId\:(\d+).*Size:(\d+)", string):
    ...:     d[cust_id].append(sz)
    ...:

In [5]: d
Out[5]: defaultdict(list, {'1234': ['5432'], '1237': ['5432']})
```

Comment: @SomanathPatil [FYI](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): "Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question."

Comment: (use upvotes instead of thank yous if you liked an answer, you can upvote multiple answers)